# Keyframe SCSS slideshow transpiled into Tailwind does not work

Tags: css, sass, tailwind-css

I need to ask for some guidance about the process I did. Here in this working example on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/krakruhahah/pen/abRQEmm) you can see this working animation in CSS.

I believe I transpiled the CSS into tailwind correctly? And I cannot figure it out since the last couple days why it doesnt work.

Here are the relevant CSS parts with Tailwind. I believe I transpiled the CSS and keyframes correctly but after applying it in my html I do not get the desired similar effect. It disappears.

I tried to add all relevant context and my Tailwind changes, at the bottom you can see the html with the applied tailwind.

What did I do wrong? Please any help is appreciated.

**So when we apply the Tailwind CSS in the html in the first part - the slideshow slideshow--hero, mainslides and slide1, slide2. slide3:**

```
<div class="wrapframe">
  <div class="slideshow slideshow--hero"> //this part I am going to change
    <div class="mainslides"> //this part I am going to change
      <div class="slide slide1"></div> //this part I am going to change
      <div class="slide slide2"></div> //this part I am going to change
      <div class="slide slide3"></div> //this part I am going to change
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slideshow slideshow--contrast slideshow--contrast--before">
    <div class="secondslides">
      <div class="slide slide1"></div>
      <div class="slide slide2"></div>
      <div class="slide slide3"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slideshow slideshow--contrast slideshow--contrast--after">
    <div class="thirdslides">
      <div class="slide slide1"></div>
      <div class="slide slide2"></div>
      <div class="slide slide3"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

**We get this:**

```
<div class="relative h-screen overflow-hidden p-20">
    <div class="absolute top-1/2 left-0 z-[3] w-full h-[85%] -translate-y-1/2 -skew-[10deg] overflow-hidden shadow-[0_0_1rem_rgba(0,0,0,.25)]">
      <div class="absolute left-0 -top-2.5 w-screen h-screen">
        <div class="animate-SlidesSet1 bg-[url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/1563356/pexels-photo-1563356.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2)]"></div>
        <div class="animate-SlidesSet2 bg-[url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/36717/amazing-animal-beautiful-beautifull.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2)]"></div>
        <div class="animate-SlidesSet3 bg-[url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/313782/pexels-photo-313782.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&w=1260&h=750&dpr=2)]"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slideshow slideshow--contrast slideshow--contrast--before">
      <div class="secondslides">
        <div class="slide slide1"></div>
        <div class="slide slide2"></div>
        <div class="slide slide3"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="slideshow slideshow--contrast slideshow--contrast--after">
      <div class="thirdslides">
        <div class="slide slide1"></div>
        <div class="slide slide2"></div>
        <div class="slide slide3"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

But the image disappears and it loosk like this part doesnt exist. What did I wrong?

I also defined the keyframes in my tailwind config and it looks in the config like this (I can also add the other keyframes if needed..):

```
SlidesSet1: {
"0%": {
 opacity: "1",
 transform: "scale(1)"
},
"31%": {
opacity: "1",
transform: "scale(1)"
},
"34%": {
opacity: "0",
transform: "scale(1.05)"
},
"97%": {
opacity: "0",
transform: "scale(1.05)"
},
"100%": {
opacity: "1",
transform: "scale(1)"
  }
},
animation: {
    SlidesSet1: "20s firstSlidesSet -0.1s infinite",
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an exhaustive list, but discrepancies I found:

- `.wrapframe` has does not apply any `padding` whereas its equivalent has `padding: 5rem` via `p-20` in the Tailwind-transposed version.
- `.wrapframe` applies `width: 100vw` whereas its equivalent has no applied `width` in the Tailwind-transposed version.
- `.slideshow--hero` applies `left: 50%; top: 0; width: 67%; height: 100%` when media query `(min-width: 600px)` is satisfied but this is not reflected in the Tailwind-transposed version.
- `.mainslides` applies `background-position: center; background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat;` whereas its equivalent has none of these values applied in the Tailwind-transposed version.
- `.slideshow--hero .mainslides` applies `top: -10%` whereas its equivalent has `top: -0.625rem` via `-top-2.5` in the Tailwind-transposed version.
- `.slideshow--hero .mainslides` applies `animation: 11s slideshow-hero-mobile -3s infinite` whereas its equivalent has no applied `animation` in the Tailwind-transposed version.
- `.slideshow--hero .mainslides` applies `top: 0; left: -25%; height: 100%; animation: 11s slideshow-hero -3s infinite;` when media query `(min-width: 600px)` is satisfied but this is not reflected in the Tailwind-transposed version.
- `.slide` applies `position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-position: center; background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat;` whereas its equivalent has none of these values applied in the Tailwind-transposed version.
- `animate-SlidesSet1` class used by the `.slide1` equivalent references `@keyframe` with identifier `firstSlidesSet` but this does not seem to have been defined in the provided configuration.
- `.slide2` applies `animation: 20s slides-set-2 -0.1s infinite` but this is not reflected in the Tailwind-transposed version.
- `.slide3` applies `animation: 20s slides-set-3 -0.1s infinite` but this is not reflected in the Tailwind-transposed version.